# how to retrieve variables from Mysql and use it in a function in JS?

Tags: javascript, java, mysql, google-maps

Hi all i wanna to add markers in a map . i should retrieve Longitude and latitude from a table in database to add markers .

> 1- i used javascript to show the map (google map).

```
    var map;
var initialize;

initialize = function(){
  var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(x,y); 
  var myOptions = {
    zoom      : 14, 
    center    : latLng, 
    mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,
    maxZoom   : 20
  };

  map      = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), myOptions);

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position : latLng,
    map      : map,
    title    : "sousse"
    //icon     : "marker_sousse.gif" 
  });
```

> 2- i retrieve Longitude and LATitude for database and i put it them in 2 String Lists using Java:

```
package beans;

import .
.
.
.
.


@ManagedBean(name = "js")
@RequestScoped
public class Map {
    ArrayList<String> Listlat = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> Listlng = new ArrayList<String>();
    GestionAnalyseLocal m;
    ResultSet resultSet;

    public Map() {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/pfedb", "root", "");
            Statement statement = connect.createStatement();
            resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select * from t_analyse");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("erreur" + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    public ArrayList<String> ExtractLat(ResultSet rs) {
        try {
            while (rs.next()) {
                Listlat.add(rs.getString("latitude"));

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("erreur" + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return Listlat;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> ExtractLng(ResultSet rs) {
        try {
            while (rs.next()) {
                Listlng.add(rs.getString("Longitude"));

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("erreur" + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return Listlng;
    }
}
```

> 3- i wanna now to find a solution that i can replace the x and y in js function with the two lists... and this is the html page :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html> 
<html >
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:jsf="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf"
    xmlns:pt="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    template="/WEB-INF/template/template.xhtml"
    >
    <ui:define name="title">Map</ui:define>
   <ui:define name="content">

  <head>


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui-1.8.12.custom.css" type="text/css" /> 
  </head>
  <style type="text/css">
    #container{position:relative;width:990px;margin:auto;}
    #container #map{width:500px;height:500px;margin:auto;}
  </style>
  <body>
    <div  id="container">
        <div id="map">
            <p>Veuillez patienter pendant le chargement de la carte...</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Include Javascript -->

    <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/jquery-ui-1.8.12.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/functions.js"></script>

  </body>
  </ui:define>
  </ui:composition>
</html>
```

**just a note : im not familiar  with Javascript :/**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use jQuery and AJAX to do that in an easy way.
Maybe you have to create a method to return both latitude and longitude.
For example:

```
$(document).ready(function(evt){
    $.get('/url/to/get/coords', function(response){
        initialize(response.longitude, response.latitude);
    });
});
```

You must ensure your new method returns a response in JSON format and modify your initialize function like this:

```
initialize = function(x,y){ your code }
```

to pass coords.

Hope it helps.